# jQuery: load ajax and create js objects

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress, rest

i am working with wp-rest api and i have this json structure to work with:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test-Font"
    },
    "acf": {
      "schrift": [
        {
          "zeichen": "A",
          "anzahl": "23"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "B",
          "anzahl": "46"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "C",
          "anzahl": "42"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "D",
          "anzahl": "49"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "E",
          "anzahl": "31"
        },

…


 {
    "id": 12,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test-Font2"
    },
    "acf": {
      "schrift": [
        {
          "zeichen": "A",
          "anzahl": "20"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "B",
          "anzahl": "12"
        },

…
```

I need to load different posts of this structure and create for each post an object with the informations about the id and the font-details (the data stored via acf)

at the moment i have this script:

```
var schrift = {}

jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/schriften/',  
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function() {   
                schrift.id = this.id;
                $.each(this.acf.schrift, function(key, value) {
                    schrift.value = value;
                });
                console.log (schrift);
            });
        }
    })
})
```

but in the new object only one information is stored, how can i loop through the whole json structure and create/store it to work with it.

What I need is: for each posts that is loaded: information about the id and the details stored with acf.

Thanks alot

**Edit:**

is it possible to restructure the json object in a js object that functions like an associative array:

Like this

```
11      //ID
  A      // zeichen 
   23    // anzahl
  B 
   46
  C
   42
```

so that its possible to get the value like this: 
`object['11'].A  // should get 23`

Comment: Why not push each `schrift` into a `schriften` array?

Comment: Why are you copying to a new object? Just use the `data` object, it has everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, as Barmar said, you can use the `data` variable that has everything you want. But if you want to reestructure the json for whatever reason:

```
var schrifts = [];//array

jQuery(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/schriften/',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (element) {
                var auxSchrift = {};
                auxSchrift.id = element.id;
                auxSchrift.acfs = [];//an array in the object
                element.acf.schrift.forEach(function (element) {
                    auxSchrift.acfs.push(element);
                });
                schrifts.push(auxSchrift);
            });
            console.log(schrifts);
        }
    });
});
```

I changed *jQuery's* `$.each()`  for the javascript *native* one `forEach` but you can place the `$.each` if you want.

Comment: thanks alot, is it possible to change the structure of the object like `[11] : [A] : 23`? thanks again?

Comment: I don't really understand that kind of structure, can you write it in a JSON way?

Comment: thanks alot I edited the question above, i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: You can't do associative arrays, arrays in javascript do not support named indexes just numeric ones. What you can do is to use objects, in this way: `{'Key': 'Value', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3'}`, but you can't do `['key'=> 'val', 'key2'=> 'val2']`. You can nest objects and arrays like `{'Key1': ['someVal', {'key': 'val'}]}`. Hope it helps. By the way if you do `someVar['someKey'] = someValueVar;` you will get an object like `{'someKey': someValue}`.